# How do I complete the subject alternative name section of powershell cmdlet

Tags: exchange-server

I have exchange 2016 running on a member server on my test network. I am trying to create an internal ssl certificate for exchange. I have installed and configured the certificate service.
I have not done this configuration before.
I am using this web page as a guide:

https://www.alitajran.com/create-certificate-exchange-server/

From what I understand, on exchange  2016, I have to create the internal ssl certificate using powershell cmdlet. I will not be using a wildcard certificate.
I do not understand what information I enter for the subject alternative name. I will be using the windows server internal certificate service. My domain name is:
photonicss.com
What information do I enter for the subject alternative name? Any advise will be appreciated.
Thank you.

[Subject alternative name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltEm5.png)

I do not know how to configure the subject alternative name section of the cmdlet.